# how do I add a triangle to the top right corner?

Tags: css

I want to add a triangle on the top right corner of the child items, but how can I achieve the following CSS element? I did the following table in order to build a matrix, but I want to add the triangle in the same div

```css
.column{
  float:left;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width:120px;
}

.column .option{
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
  padding:10px;
  background:#22244a;
}

.column .option:first-child{
  background:#EBEDEE;
}

.column .option:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   display: block;
   border-left: 35px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
   border-top: 35px solid #0094bb;
   z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to the closest parent with the `position` property different from `static`, which is default.

Just changed this

```
.column .option {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.column{
  float:left;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width:120px;
}

.column .option{
  position: relative;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
  padding:10px;
  background:#22244a;
}

.column .option:first-child{
  background:#EBEDEE;
}

.column .option:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   display: block;
   border-left: 35px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
   border-top: 35px solid #0094bb;
   z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Edit: [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute_positioning).